# Count unique values from a column of a random file by shell command

Tags: shell

I have a file named `c01_1_664_blastx.blast`. And it has contents like below

```
c1_g1_i1    sp|P87048|RPN1_SCHPO    63.83   47      16      1       20      160     840     885     5e-09   57.9
c3_g1_i1    sp|Q6DCX2|AGO2_XENLA    58.02   131     45      3       567     199     733     861     3e-61     149
..................
...................
...................
```

I need to count the number of unique values in the first column(c1_g1_i1, c3_g1_i1) by a shell command. Can any one help me with this?
Thanks in advance..Cheers

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: For the above example the output should be `2`

Comment: Yes, since the column values are different(`c3_g1_i1` and `c1_g1_i1`).

Answer (score 2):

```
cut -d' ' -f 1  input_file | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

You can use `cut` to specify the delimiter and the fields you want to extract. After extract the first field, you `sort` it and then apply `uniq` to get the unique entries and count the number of such entries by just piping it to `wc`. Note that you could use `uniq -c` to get a count of the number of times each unique entry appears.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need multiple piped command for this. A single `awk` can handle this:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++{} END{print length(seen)}' file
2
```

Or:

```
awk '!seen[$1]++{i++} END{print i}' file
```

This awk command maintains an associative array `seen` to hold only unique values and in the `END` section it just prints length of array.